# connect to server2016 via rdp through ipv6

Tags: windows, ipv6, sql-server-2016, rdp

i try to connect to my server via rdp
my server ip address is  :

```
2001:41d0:1008:135a::1
```

but can't connect to rdp.
I have tried these methods:

```
[2001:41d0:1008:135a::1]
```

[image]

```
2001-41d0-1008-135a--1.ipv6-literal.net
```

[image]

But none worked.

Answer (score 0):

enclose the IPv6 address in square brackets. 
So for IPv6 address `fd94:8414:eef6:325d::c0a8:1302`and port `45001`, you would use `[fd94:8414:eef6:325d::c0a8:1302]:45001`

OR

Just Use IPv4

```
192.168.X.XXX
```

Comment: 1-not work . get same error
2-i haven't ipv4
[error image ](https://imgur.com/a/bzvFo)

Comment: Is IPv6 Remote Access Enabed On The Host

Comment: Is not enabled by default ?

Comment: Not Sure. I Would Still Check

Comment: At The Moment Does It Have A Working Network Connection

Comment: yes. 
Is it necessary to have an IPv6 on my client(mypc) to connect to the server ?

Comment: I Think You Do Yes